# How to search then select a string among double quote in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex

I have a variable named `MyText` in type of `String` as below:

```
"XYZ_abcdefgh..."
```

Note that `abcdefgh...` means that we don't know exactly what is it (simply say: it changes).

Now I want to select all of `XYZ_abcdefgh...` by this mean and put it in another variable like `MyExportedText`:

**SELECT ALL STRINGS BETWEEN DOUBLE QUOTE WITCH STARTS WITH 'XYZ'**

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework request.

Comment: Please be helpful @ppeterka

Comment: I have tried this regex `\"(.*?)\"`. @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: @ramirez then you almost had the answer. Just a little more trying with 'XYZ' and you'd have the result faster than it took you asking here :-) There are nice websites where you can test your RegEx by the way.

Comment: Oh! That's true @HubertGrzeskowiak. My purpose is enrich Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Java [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). Essentially you can enclose part of the regex in round brackets to "capture" them and extract them from the input `String`.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this regex to validate your string 

/^(?:[XYZ]{3,})([a-z]*)$/g

for reference check this link
   https://regex101.com/r/cV8xL2/1
```

Comment: Not your business @ppeterka

Comment: No problem ramirez